# Embedding with an INET linked project on Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm trying to simulate some tsn INET networks using *Embedding* project with a few changes in main(). However, the simulation terminates at the network setup phase (setupNetwork()) and, exactly inside buildRecursively(). The main.cc functions are as shown below:

```
void simulate(cSimulation *simulation, const char *networkName, simtime_t limit)
{
    // set up the network
    cModuleType *networkType = cModuleType::find(networkName);

    if (networkType == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "No such network as" << networkName << "\n" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (networkType->isNetwork()) {
        std::cout << networkName << " is a network\n" << endl;
    }

    if (getSimulation()->getActiveSimulation() == simulation) {
        std::cout << "Sim is active!\n" << endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Setting up the network..\n" << endl;
    //getSimulation()->setupNetwork(networkType); //XXX may throw exception
    simulation->setupNetwork(networkType); //XXX may throw exception
    std::cout << "Setting the sim time limit..\n" << endl;
    //getSimulation()->setSimulationTimeLimit(limit);
    simulation->setSimulationTimeLimit(limit);

    std::cout << "Calling the initialize()..\n" << endl;
    // prepare for running it
    getSimulation()->callInitialize();

    // run the simulation
    bool ok = true;
    try {
        while (true) {
            cEvent *event = getSimulation()->takeNextEvent();
            if (!event)
                break;  //XXX
            getSimulation()->executeEvent(event);
        }
    }
    catch (cTerminationException& e) {
        printf("Finished: %s\n", e.what());
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        ok = false;
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", e.what());
    }

    if (ok)
        getSimulation()->callFinish();  //XXX may throw exception

    // finish the simulation and clean up the network
    getSimulation()->deleteNetwork();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // the following line MUST be at the top of main()
    cStaticFlag dummy;

    // initializations
    CodeFragments::executeAll(CodeFragments::STARTUP);
    SimTime::setScaleExp(-12);


    const char *libName = "../inet4.5/src/libINET_dbg.dll";//please change this to libINET.dll to perform the simulation, for now
    if (!LoadLibrary(libName))
        std::cout << "INET lib's not loaded successfully\n" << endl;
    else
         std::cout << "INET lib loaded successfully\n" << endl;
    CodeFragments::executeAll(CodeFragments::STARTUP);

    // initialize coroutine library
    //cCoroutine::init(4096, 0);

    std::cout << "loading  NED files\n" << endl;
    // load NED files
    int inet_files = cSimulation::loadNedSourceFolder(".");
    std::cout << "Number of files loaded :" << inet_files << "\n" << endl;
    inet_files = cSimulation::loadNedSourceFolder("../inet4.5/examples", "inet.examples.emulation;inet.examples.voipstream");
    std::cout << "Number of files loaded :" << inet_files << "\n" << endl;
    inet_files = cSimulation::loadNedSourceFolder("../inet4.5/showcases", "inet.showcases.emulation;inet.showcases.visualizer.osg");
    std::cout << "Number of files loaded :" << inet_files << "\n" << endl;
    inet_files = cSimulation::loadNedSourceFolder("../inet4.5/src", "inet.applications.voipstream;inet.common.selfdoc;inet.emulation;inet.linklayer.configurator.gatescheduling.z3;inet.transportlayer.tcp_lwip;inet.visualizer.osg");
    std::cout << "Number of files loaded :" << inet_files << "\n" << endl;
    inet_files = cSimulation::loadNedSourceFolder("../inet4.5/tests/validation");
    std::cout << "Number of files loaded :" << inet_files << "\n" << endl;
    inet_files = cSimulation::loadNedSourceFolder("../inet4.5/tests/networks");
    std::cout << "Number of files loaded :" << inet_files << "\n" << endl;
    inet_files = cSimulation::loadNedSourceFolder("../inet4.5/tutorials");
    std::cout << "Number of files loaded :" << inet_files << "\n" << endl;
    cSimulation::doneLoadingNedFiles();

    std::cout << "setting up the environment..\n" << endl;
    // set up an environment for the simulation
    cConfiguration *bootconfig = new EmptyConfig();

    cEnvir *env = new MinimalEnv(argc, argv, bootconfig);
    cSimulation *sim = new cSimulation("simulation", env);
    cSimulation::setActiveSimulation(sim);

    std::cout << "starting simulation..\n" << endl;
    // set up and run a simulation model
    simulate(sim,"SimpleTsn", 10000);

    // exit
    cSimulation::setActiveSimulation(nullptr);
    delete sim;
    delete bootconfig;

    // deallocate registration lists, loaded NED files, etc.
    CodeFragments::executeAll(CodeFragments::SHUTDOWN);
    return 0;
}
```

The Debug console output is as follows:

```
INET lib loaded successfully
loading  NED files
Number of files loaded :1
Number of files loaded :175
Number of files loaded :70
Number of files loaded :1139
Number of files loaded :5
Number of files loaded :6
Number of files loaded :20
setting up the environment..
starting simulation..
SimpleTsn is a network
Sim is active!
Setting up the network..
```

During debugging, the simulation stopped inside cNedNetworkBuilder::buildRecursively() at this line.

```
void cNedNetworkBuilder::buildRecursively(cModule *modp, cNedDeclaration *decl)
{
    // recursively add super types' submodules and connections
    if (decl->numExtendsNames() > 0) {
        const char *superName = decl->getExtendsName(0);
        cNedDeclaration *superDecl = cNedLoader::getInstance()->getDecl(superName);
        buildRecursively(modp, superDecl);
    }

    **currentDecl = decl;  // switch "context"**
    addSubmodulesAndConnections(modp);
}
```

Here, it first executes this function for a few times (until it reaches the base network, I think) and then when the if condition fails for the first time, the simulation is terminating.

Do I need to add anything else in main.cc? Is there something that I'm missing? Can you please help?

Thank you in advance!